# Is there anyway in flex to get the status of server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache-flex

we have an application where button click in flex side restarts the server and makes the client logged out. once after logout, If user logs in it gives error since the server is not up  by the time. In our scenario the server takes time to restart because of the stuff(like back up). I want the user to be notified of the webserver status if he tries to log in.

is there any way to monitor the status of server in Flex side. or Will javascript help in finding whether the server is up or not?.

Also I tried redirecting to html page using external interface but I am not sure how to automatically redirect it again to the swf file when the server becomes active.the server downtime is not known(may be 2 or 5 or 10 minutes.)

So what would be the best approach.Any help would be of greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) you can try to download a file on the server and listen to ioError or httpStatus.

```
private var testLoader:URLLoader;
private var testRequest:URLRequest;

...

testRequest = new URLRequest("http://server/testFile");
testLoader = new URLLoader(request);
testLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatus);

private function onStatus(HTTPStatusEvent:event):void
{
    //test the status, if the server is up, reconnect, else...
    testLoader.load(testRequest);
}
```

Comment: Since the server is down and therefore the authentication killed, you don't really need https for this test.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  When you mean restart, do you mean just a specific service like Apache or like an actual reboot of the server?  I ask because it would mean different scenarios.  I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but I'll assume that you're rebooting the server.

One of the problems here is that the client logs out, which is something we do not want.  What I would do is have a second server which it's sole purpose would be authentication and giving status on the other server.  This is a 'man in the middle' approach where this server doesn't log you out, but all calls are redirected to the other server.

From the Flex side, you can have it calls the 'man in the middle' to see what's the status.  Depending on the technology you're using (polling vs pushing), you can get the data needed and show the user the status.

Comment: Actually we have both the cases, but first, we stop our jboss server, do some backing up of DB,restart the db service and again we start the jboss server.so by the time it experiences downtime.. I want the client notified about the downtime and re-connect to the same once webserver resumes. Is there not any interface flex provides like urlmonitor in AIR.. or any socket listener wud do ?